# What does 'none' mean in "mount -t cgroup -o cpuset none /cpuset"

Tags: linux, mount, cgroups

When practising cgroup, we need mount like `mount -t cgroup -o cpuset none /cpuset`

Would you explain the significance of `none` here?

Seems it's just a name and I could set it as any string, right?

Is there any file, folder or file contant based on it?

Comment: [Here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136646/what-is-type-none-for-mount-points-and-why-are-mount-points-of-the-same-type-b) it is already answered.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain filesystems aren't associated with a physical `device` (such as a partition or network share, which is what is expected at that point in the `mount` command) and it is/was customary to use `none` for these. I've seen a more reasonable approach, using a more descriptive name, eg. `cpuset` in your case.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So in case I set it as a weird name and is there any thing affected by it?

Comment: Anything goes really, but keep in mind that mount/unmount errors use the selected name, so choose sensibly for the sake of your own sanity :-)